# Israel's Official Gazette online?

Tags: israel, resource

Since 1948, Israel's Official Gazette has detailed all of the bills and notices of Israel's government, making it a mine of historical information.

The [website of the Israel State Archives](http://www.archives.gov.il/ArchiveGov_Eng/Our+Holdings/official/) says:

> The collections include Rashumot, the Official Gazette (consisting of the Government Notices, Bills, the Book of Laws, the Treaty Series, etc), [...]

Written by Ben Gurion, [the first issue](http://www.knesset.gov.il/docs/eng/megilat_eng.htm) is also known as the Proclamation of Independence.

**QUESTION:** Can the Official Gazette be seen online?
It does not seem to be readable on the website of the Israel State Archives.

Comment: Could you please explain how this is a question about history?

Comment: @Drux: Thanks for the feedback! I added why it is a publication of historical significance.

Comment: This is more of a "meta" question. Marked as such.

Comment: It sounds more on-topic here: http://libraries.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/where-can-israels-official-gazette-be-found